# on hover thumbnails play

Tags: javascript, video, jquery, thumbnails

i have several videos on my server and three thumbnails for every video what i want is if i put  mouse on the video it shows(play) all the thumbnails of that video 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have static and animated version of each thumbnail.
One of simplest solutions would be to use:

```
<div style='width:100p; height:100px; background:url(static_thumb.gif)'></div>
```

and then to all such divs apply:

```
$('your divs').hover(
function(){ $(this).html('<img src='+process($(this).css('background-image'))+'>') },
function(){ $(this).empty() }
);
```

and lastly you need to specify the process function, that will change url(static_thumb.gif) into something like ani_thumb.gif.